# Styling the items in the CKEditor Format Combo box?

Tags: css, format, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In CKEditor 4, items shown in the "Styles" combo box are displayed with their styles, demonstrating how the text will be styled if the item is selected.

This is not the case for the "Format" combo box items for block-level formatting. Is there a way to fix this? For example by "cheating" and manually adding a CSS class to each item that mimics how the paragraph style will look?

Comment: Does this help? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_format.html#custom-block-level-text-formats-definition
You can override the formats with other HTML tags with custom attributes (e.g. class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this in config.js

```
  config.fontSize_style={
            element:        'font',
            attributes: { 'class': 'fs-#(size)' }
        };
```

which will add class="fs-selectedFontSize"
for eg class="fs-18". 
Then you have to add style for such classes in contents.css or link your CSS file. For similar techniques go to the official website of [CKEditor Guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/index.html)
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/index.html